# Unit testing in PHPUnit with Twig installed

Tags: php, phpunit, twig

When I run PHPUnit, it tries to run test files in unexpected locations, namely the Twig install directory, and tries to load Twig class files too many times. Does anyone know how to fix these problems?

## Background

I am using [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) (just Twig, not Symfony) in a web app, with Twig installed via Composer. Composer and Twig are installed in custom locations, and my tests are in `/test/`, so I have the following simplified project structure:

```
/src/includes/vendor/
    autoload.php
    composer/
    twig/
        twig/
            lib/
            test/
/test/
    bootstrap.php
    (various files named, e.g., someClassTest.php)
```

My bootstrap file (`/test/bootstrap.php`) does nothing other than load the Composer autoloader:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../src/includes/vendor/autoload.php";
```

My PHPUnit config file (phpunit.xml) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="All Tests">
            <directory>./test/phpunit/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <ini name="xdebug.default_enable" value="0" />
        <ini name="xdebug.remote_autostart" value="0" />
        <ini name="xdebug.remote_enable" value="0" />
        <ini name="xdebug.overload_var_dump" value="0" />
        <ini name="xdebug.show_mem_delta" value="0" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

## The Problems

**1. PHPUnit is running the Twig unit tests in `/src/includes/vendor/composer/twig/twig/test/`.**

Why? Based on my config file, I would expect only tests in `/test` to run. For now, I have created a separate config file that explicitly excludes the Twig tests with this entry:

```
<exclude>./src/includes/vendor/</exclude>
```

This feels hacky and brittle, and I don't see why it's necessary. Can anyone explain this?

**2. If I try to run PHPUnit without explicitly excluding the Twig unit tests, I run into autoloader problems.**

If I run PHPUnit without including my bootstrap.php file, then the Composer autoloader isn't loaded, so PHPUnit dies the first time it tries to instantiate any Twig classes.

If I include the autoloader, classes get loaded twice and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Twig_Node_Expression_Test in [path to project]\src\includes\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Test.php on line 32

Call Stack:
    0.1630     223296   1. {main}() C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:0
    0.4280     857528   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:552
    0.4280     864000   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:294
    1.8451    1338552   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() phar://C:/Users/Ed/Documents/Programming/phpunit-lts.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:150
  107.4751    1501304   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() phar://C:/Users/Ed/Documents/Programming/phpunit-lts.phar/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:96
  107.6552    1668912   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() phar://C:/Users/Ed/Documents/Programming/phpunit-lts.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:416
  107.6572    1668888   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() phar://C:/Users/Ed/Documents/Programming/phpunit-lts.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:355
  107.6592    1669056   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() phar://C:/Users/Ed/Documents/Programming/phpunit-lts.phar/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
```

I have not had any similar problems actually running the application; this only happens when unit testing.

If it helps, I am running PHPStorm 9 (PS-141.1717), using PHPUnit 3.7.37.

Does anyone have insight into this issue?

---

**Edit based on comment:** The command line that PHPStorm is executing is as follows:

> C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:/Users/Ed/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap [path to project]\test\phpunit\bootstrap.php --configuration [path to project]\phpunit.xml [path to project]

Comment: What is the command you're using to run your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer by tinkering around with PHPStorm quite a bit. In the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog, I had "Directory" checked as the "Test scope." I changed that to "Defined in the configuration file."

[image: Screenshot of PHPStorm Run/Debug Configuration dialog]

Now, PHPUnit only runs the tests in `/test/phpunit/`, as specified in my `phpunit.xml`. This means it doesn't run the Twig tests (as expected), eliminating both of the problems specified in my question. This works if I run the tests from within PHPStorm and also if I simply execute the command `phpunit` on the terminal while in the directory containing `phpunit.xml`.

All that said, if anyone knows how to run *both* my tests and the Twig tests simultaneously, without getting "Cannot redeclare class" errors, please post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your PHPUnit command, try replacing `[path to project]` with `[path to project]/tests/phpunit`, or omitting that part entirely.

Comment: That command is automatically generated and executed by PHPStorm. I have no direct control over it.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid it is that command which is at fault.  PHPUnit is searching the entire directory structure, including your 3rd party dependencies, for extensions of `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.  Giving it the path to *your* tests, or giving it nothing so it uses the path you defined in your `phpunit.xml` file would work.  If your IDE can't cope with that, maybe run the `phpunit` command in a terminal?